# Exchange 2010 search mailbox specific date range

Tags: exchange-2010

I've been using Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 SP2. I want to delete user's mails within specific date range. How can I do that? BTW, When to running below command then I've got the following the error.

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity xxxxx -SearchQuery "Received:> $('01/01/2009') and Received:< $('12/31/2009')" -DeleteContent
```

Here is my error message :

```
A search keyword should not be preceeded with comparison modifiers eg. '<', '>', '='.    
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], ParserException    
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 61B67608
```

UPDATE :

As you mentioned,I've done literally your comments. But ,

Even though about 6000 emails within user's mailbox,it's returned 18 emails below command.

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity xxxxxxx -SearchQuery {((Received -lt '01 Oct 2009') -and (Received -gt '01 Aug 2013'))} -TargetMailbox targetmailbox -TargetFolder testxx -LogOnly
```

Comment: replace the > and < with -gt and -lt.

Comment: I've updated my post.

Comment: Any comments?..

Comment: so you want email prior to 10/1/2009 and after 8/1/2013? not between?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for you error is because special characters are not escaped. The easiest way is to use double quotes around the value instead of single quotes.  Also if you'd like to use a date range then you can use the '..' operator.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558911(v=office.15).aspx#kql_property_restriction_queries

So `Search-Mailbox xxxxx -SearchQuery "Received:(1/1/2009..12/31/2009)"`

This will search for all mail received between 1/1/2009 12:00 am and 12/31/2009 12:00 am.

Answer (score 0):

I am on the same version of Exchange2010, the syntax is different when you use the {} versus not using it

Search-mailbox -identity xxxxx -searchQuery {received:>12/31/2008 AND received:<1/1/2010} -TargetMailbox targetmailbox -TargetFolder testxx -LogOnly

or

Search-mailbox -identity xxxxx -searchQuery received:>12/31/2008, received:<1/1/2010 -TargetMailbox targetmailbox -TargetFolder testxx -LogOnly

Replace the -LogOnly to -DeleteContent if it needs to be removed
Which does the same thing essentially